# Android java sending a JSON post request, body is empty

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to send a simple request using Java for Android. I have implemented a script and everything seems to be working fine the request is being sent but the most important part the JSON object just doesnt show up on the backend, the body of the request is completely empty.

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String titleData = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String textData = intent.getStringExtra("text");
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            textview.setTextSize(20);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B0719"));
            textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(packageName + "<br><b>" + titleData + " : </b>" + textData));
            tr.addView(textview);
            tab.addView(tr);

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://[hidden].herokuapp.com/api");
                try {

                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    con.setRequestProperty("token", "secret");
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        jObjectData.put("package", packageName);
                        jObjectData.put("titleData", titleData);
                        jObjectData.put("textData", textData);
                    }catch(JSONException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }

                    System.out.println(jObjectData);
                    byte[] outputInBytes = jObjectData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                    os.write( outputInBytes );
                    os.close();

                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                        String responseLine = null;
                        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(responseLine.trim());
                        }
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                    }
                }catch (IOException ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }
    };
```

I know some things are really messy its because i am very new to java and android, i just need to make this simple script work. The json object is `jObjectData` which forwards a notification to api, the problem is that whenever i send the request its body wont show up on my Node.js Express backend. The body shows up as `{}`, i am completely stuck how can i fix this?

Comment: I have checked your code and I didn't think your code has any issues. I copied it and run on my project using my API. It runs smoothly. I think you should check your manifest if you forgot to add your internet permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> before application tag starts! I would also recommend you to migrate to Retrofit to invoke APIs with ease! also please inform me if you have any specific logs in LogCat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason the `utf-8` causes this issue.
So instead of

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
```

I wrote

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and now it works, i have no idea why this is happening, maybe there's some cross configuration about the encoding that caused my server to not recognize the body.